# Rotating container indefinitely

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to rotate an Image indefinitely.

This container is one of the widget within the stack and would like this to be rotating continuously non stop.

```
final AnimationController animation = AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1800),
  vsync: const NonStopVSync(),
)..repeat();

final Tween tween = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: math.pi);

var square = Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  transform: Matrix4.identity(),
  color: Colors.amber,
);

...

class Foo extends State<Bar> {
    ...


    animation.addListener((){
       square.transform = Matrix4.rotationZ(tween.evaluate(animation));
    });

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
           children: [
              ...
              Center(
                 child: square
              )
           ]
        )
    }
}
```

and I get this `error: 'transform' can't be used as a setter because it's final. (assignment_to_final at [digital_clock] lib/digital_clock.dart:139)`

How would I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class InfiniteAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final int durationInSeconds;

  InfiniteAnimation({@required this.child, this.durationInSeconds = 2,});

  @override
  _InfiniteAnimationState createState() => _InfiniteAnimationState();
}

class _InfiniteAnimationState extends State<InfiniteAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
​
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: widget.durationInSeconds),
    );
    animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: 12.5664, // 2Radians (360 degrees)
    ).animate(animationController);
​
    animationController.forward();
​
    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        animationController.repeat();
      }
    });
  }
​
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (context, child) => Transform.rotate(
        angle: animation.value,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController?.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

---

You basically need to create a `StatefulWidget` that mixes in (`with` keyword) the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`, provide an `AnimationController`, start the animation, then when the animation completes, repeat.

The `AnimationBuilder` is a better way of telling the widget to update on every frame without having to listen to the `animationController` and call `setState` explicitly.

You can use it like this:

```
InfiniteAnimation(
  durationInSeconds: 2, // this is the default value
  child: Icon(
    Icons.expand_more,
    size: 50.0,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a lot more insight. I'm new in Dart and Flutter and finding my way through it.

Currently I'm trying to implement in this class. `https://github.com/flutter/flutter_clock/blob/master/digital_clock/lib/digital_clock.dart`

Making some design element to be constantly rotating.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need more detail on anything.

Comment: I implemented the class, in my `_DigitalClockState` class in the link in my previous comment, and I'm getting `StatefulWidget.createState must return a subtype of State<InfiniteAnimation>`

Comment: Change `State<InfiniteAnimation>` to `State<DigitalClock>`

Comment: Can my main class `_DigitalClockState` use the second class I created `InfiniteAnimation` along with the class `DigitalClock`? like in `https://github.com/flutter/flutter_clock/blob/master/digital_clock/lib/digital_clock.dart#L32`?

Comment: There's so much code in this file I'm not sure what you're referring to. Can you give an example of what you mean when you say, "like in <link>"?

Comment: Sorry. Here is the update repo which includes your suggestion. `https://github.com/nomadme/digital_clock/blob/master/lib/digital_clock.dart`

Comment: on Line 58, I already have a class called DigitalClock that creates the state.

My question was, how can I use the InfiniteAnimation class along with the class DigitalClock in the main class I'm using `_DigitalClockState` class which is building the widget.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is make something rotate infinitely, the class I provided can just be copy/pasted below your clock class (or preferably in another file and imported). Then you can just use it inside your digital clock class. No need to merge the classes together.